# Python with statement - is there a need for old-style file handling any more?

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

With having the `with` statement, is there ever a need to open a file/check for exceptions/do manual closing of resources, like in

```
try:
  f = open('myfile.txt')

  for line in f:
    print line
except IOError:
  print 'Could not open/read file'
finally:
  f.close()
```

Comment: no .....................

Comment: Could you please show how you'd use the `with` statement to do the same thing?

Comment: with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data

Comment: Your code makes no sense: If there was `IOError` raised, what are you closing in `finally`?

Comment: Please fix the code and provide the `with` example in addition to the non-`with` example.  Your "question" is hard to follow.  Indeed, it might be nothing more than a blog posting and not a real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code tries to handle the exception of the file not being found, or of insufficient access permissions etc., which a `with open(file) as f:` block wouldn't have done.

Also, in this case, the `finally:` block would have raised a `NameError` since `f` wouldn't have been defined.

In a `with` block, any exception (of whatever kind, maybe a division by zero in your code) that occurs *within the block* will still be raised, but even if you don't handle it, your file will always be closed properly. That's something entirely different.

What you want is probably:

```
try:
    with open("myfile.txt") as f:
        do_Stuff()  # even if this raises an exception, f will be closed.
except IOError:
    print "Couldn't open/read myfile.txt"
```

Comment: Splitting hairs: the finally would raise a NameError if the IOError was thrown in opening the file, not in the `for line in f` loop, because `f` would be defined by that point. A minor correction, as most IOErrors would probably occur during file opening.